# OS X - Play mp3 outside of mainBundle

Tags: xcode, macos, mp3

I would like to play an mp3 file outside of the mainBundle (from any location on the hard-drive).

That was my attempt (doesn't work):

```
NSString* theFileName = [filepath stringByDeletingPathExtension];

NSLog(@"%@", theFileName); // -> /Volumes/Data%20HD/Music/iTunes/Music/Linkin%20Park/Hybrid%20Theory/01%20Papercut

NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *filePath2 = [mainBundle pathForResource:theFileName ofType:@"mp3" ];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath2];
NSError *error2;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error2];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NSSound](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_19).

```
NSURL* file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Music/1.mp3"];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file byReference:NO];
[sound play];
```